# What is point of calling syscalls in the kernel?

Tags: operating-systems

If syscalls are meant to transition into kernel mode from user mode, what is the point of calling syscalls in the kernel?

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841327/can-we-call-system-call-in-kernel-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS also adheres to the DRY principle, reusing code that has already been implemented by developers. For example, the kernel could open/close/write to the log file, allowing it to reuse the syscall implementation rather than re-implementing it wherever it is needed.

"Write the core implementation once, reuse it when needed" is a good software engineering. Be it either in user space or kernel space.

Reference:  https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/17incss/what_is_point_of_calling_syscalls_in_the_kernel/

Answer (score 2):

Most modern operating systems have threads that run in kernel mode. Some typical examples include:

- Device drivers. Some operating systems even go to the trouble of implementing interrupt handlers as very-high-priority tasks.
- Determining page frames that haven't been used recently so they can be dealt with (e.g. writing dirty buffer cache, freeing clean page frames, recalculating user process working set sizes).
- Periodic housekeeping tasks such as balancing interrupts between CPUs in a multiprocessor system.
- An idle thread, which "runs" (if you can call sleeping in a lower-power mode "running") when nothing else can run on a CPU. Not all operating systems idle this way, but many do.

Such threads may not perform "system calls" as such, but might still use the system call entry points so that, as far as scheduling is concerned, they are just another thread and don't need special treatment.

Comment: So basically a normal thread like data structure, but with the highest integrity. Thanks for clarifying.